# Can we run sample-app that comes with BB Push SDK without app.id?

Tags: blackberry, push-notification

I am trying to deploy the sample-app war file that comes with PushSDK.But was not able to deploy the application successfully.
Steps followed till now

1) I was able to configure `PushSDK.properties` `log4j.xml`but didn't change value of `${sampleapp.appid}` in  `sample-app-context.xml`.

2)then made the war file using `cmd`

3) Deployed on the server.

during deployment an **error** was coming.

```
Invalid bean definition with name 'registerListeners' defined in class path resource [sample-app-context.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'sampleapp.appid'
```

Tried to register on [link](https://www.blackberry.com/profile/?eventId=8121) but was unsuccessful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just started down the path of using the Push SDK, but from what I've read I conclude that you need to get your development registration completed at least before you can run the sample code; unles you're using your own BES.

Comment: But I this correct BES needs MS Exchange server or MS small business server?        Another problem is,When tried to get register and get ID for evaluation version, Blackberry has disabled 1 check box in last part of the form,that for agreement with their terms and conditions,SO unable to even Submit the request there?any alternate solution?

Comment: Ther is the MDS server only version of the BES which does not provide the groupware integration. In order to get the submit button active you have to "read" the terms of service agreement.

Comment: Thanx was able register.Can you please suggest me any good tuts for Push API other than those on Blackberry site.

Comment: Not for the push API, but here is a link that taught me the most about how the MDS server works. I don't know how applicable it will be to using the PUSH API because I've just started that. http://blog.fupps.com/documents/blackberry/real-world-blackberry-mds-push-applications-an-extensible-framework/